# How to find the latest version of an OS programmatically?

Tags: python, operating-system

How can I find the latest version of macOS and Windows programmatically?

I'm looking for an official API where I can query from Apple and Microsoft to find the latest version of their platforms, e.g. 13.1 and 22H2 22621.1250.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page: https://endoflife.date/

Hope this helps.

Comment: A simple link to another site is rarely a useful answer, and most users will not click through unless they know what the site is. As presented, this should be assumed to be a Phishing post or useless link post. This should be removed.

Comment: Not a malicious site but not useful since the question specifically refers to OS EOL and the suggested website does not provide information for either MacOS or Windows